# How to select fields after aggregation in Elastic Search 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following schema for an index:-

```
 PUT
    "mappings": {
        "event": {
          "properties": {
            "@timestamp": { "type": "date",    "doc_values": true},
            "partner_id":  { "type": "integer", "doc_values": true},
            "event_id": { "type": "integer", "doc_values": true},
            "count": { "type": "integer", "doc_values": true, "index": "no" },
            "device_id": { "type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed","doc_values":true }
            "product_id": { "type": "integer", "doc_values": true},
          }
        }
      }
```

I need result equivalent to following query:-

```
SELECT product_id, device_id, sum(count) FROM index WHERE partner_id=5 AND timestamp<=end_date AND timestamp>=start_date GROUP BY device_id,product_id having sum(count)>1;
```

I am able to achieve the result by following elastic query:-

```
GET
{
    "store": true,
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "matching_events":{
            "filter":{
                "bool":{
                    "must":[
                        {
                            "term":{
                                "partner_id":5
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range":{
                                "@timestamp":{
                                    "from":1470904000,
                                    "to":1470904999
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggs":{
                      "group_by_productid": {
                      "terms":{
                        "field":"product_id"
                    },
            "aggs":{
                "group_by_device_id":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"device_id"
                    },
                    "aggs":{
                        "total_count":{
                            "sum":{
                                "field":"count"
                            }
                        },
                        "sales_bucket_filter":{
                            "bucket_selector":{
                                "buckets_path":{
                                    "totalCount":"total_count"
                                },
                                "script": {"inline": "totalCount > 1"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }}
                }
            }
        }
    }

}'
```

However for the case where `count is <=1` query is returning empty buckets with key as `product_id`. Now out of 40 million groups, only 100k will have satisfy the condition, so I am returned with huge result set, majority of which is useless. How can I select only particular field after aggregation? I tried this but not working- `"fields": ["aggregations.matching_events.group_by_productid.group_by_device_id.buckets.key"]

**Edit:**

I have following set of data:-

```
 device id                       Partner Id         Count 
db63te2bd38672921ffw27t82        367                   3
db63te2bd38672921ffw27t82        272                   1
```

I go this output:-

```
{

    "took":6,
    "timed_out":false,
    "_shards":{
        "total":5,
        "successful":5,
        "failed":0
    },
    "hits":{
        "total":7,
        "max_score":0.0,
        "hits":[
        ]
    },
    "aggregations":{
        "matching_events":{
            "doc_count":5,
            "group_by_productid":{
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                "buckets":[
                    {
                        "key":367,
                        "doc_count":3,
                        "group_by_device_id":{
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                            "buckets":[
                                {
                                    "key":"db63te2bd38672921ffw27t82",
                                    "doc_count":3,
                                    "total_count":{
                                        "value":3.0
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key":272,
                        "doc_count":1,
                        "group_by_device_id":{
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                            "buckets":[
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, bucket with key 272 is empty which make sense, but shouldn't this bucket be removed from result set altogether?

Comment: Have you tried `top_hits` aggregation?

Comment: Nopes, but as I understand top_hit returns the best matching documents. For me, matching is boolean - yes or no. There shouldn't any score if match is there. May be I don't understand it completely!

Comment: I think I didn't understand the requirement. You want to filter out `group_by_device_id` buckets where the `sales_bucket_filter` result is empty (meaning the sub-buckets have already been filtered)?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks for the help. I have added more details in the question.

Comment: Yup, only show the aggregations where we have non empty buckets!

Comment: Pfff, that's difficult. I remember a short while back I looked at a similar post on SO and I couldn't find a solution then. The idea is that in the "root" aggregation you can't really access the leaf aggregation (the one that makes the decision of keeping the bucket or not).

Comment: I was also thinking in the same direction. This is going to be a bummer, because this will end up returning lots of useless data in the result set (High I/O over network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found out that there is a fairly recent issue and PR that adds a `_bucket_count` path to a `buckets_path` option so that an aggregation can potentially filter the parent bucket based on the number of buckets another aggregation has. In other words if the `_bucket_count` is 0 for a parent `bucket_selector` the bucket should be removed.

This is the github issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19553

Comment: Awesome, but as I understand it is not the part of version 2.3 right?

Comment: Yes, it will be available in ES 5.